# ASCII code for special character in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I would like to know the code ASCII for the caracter like: '•' ,'■'for database Oracle (Oracle Form)

Answer (score 1):

Use the ASCII function.

```
select ASCII('•'), ASCII('■') FROM DUAL;

ASCII('•') = 149
ASCII('■') = 166
```

To implement use

```
select chr(149),chr(166) from dual;
```

Comment: 149 return •  but 166 return ¦

Comment: same here chr(166) returns ¦, did not also find the blackbox when i ran this query, "SELECT rownum, CHR(rownum) FROM dual CONNECT BY rownum < 256;". In windows, blackbox's ascii is 254.

Comment: @mohamedsaied  check in your database for select  ASCII('■') FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the character set your are using. For ASCII (which is 7-bit) `•` and `■` do not exist.

In case of Windows Codepage (e.g. CP 1252) you can use `CHR(149)` for `•`, i.e. [U+2022](https://codepoints.net/U+2022) or use `UNISTR('\2022')`.

`■` ([U+25A0](https://codepoints.net/U+25A0)) seems to be not supported by any Windows 125x encoding, use `UNISTR('\25A0')`.

In case your character set is `AL32UTF8` and your national character set is `AL16UTF16` you can also use `NCHR(8226)` or `CHR(14844066)` for `•` and `NCHR(9632)` or `CHR(14849696)` for `■`

See https://unicode-table.com/en/25A0/ and https://unicode-table.com/en/2022/ to find out the decimal numbers for UTF-8 and UTF-16

Comment: when i use UNISTR('\25A0') in oracle forms6i error message identifier unistr must be declared

Comment: Forms 6i is an ancient piece of software and its PL/SQL engine doesn't (didn't) keep up with database's improvements and new functionalities. If you can execute UNISTR in your database, then create a (stored) function which will *wrap* UNISTR and return value to your Forms application. For most cases it works OK, I don't know whether it'll be OK in this specific case.